# How to pass array of ctypes structures to pyOpenCL?

Tags: python, opencl, ctypes, pyopencl

I have been following along with a tutorial online using OpenCL, where I am doing everything using python and pyOpenCL. As a stripped down example of my problem, I need to pass an array of C structs as an argument to an OpenCL kernel.

Here is an artificial example of OpenCL code:

```
typedef struct Test{
    float a;
    float3 b;
} Test;

__kernel void render_kernel(__constant Test *tests, const int width, const int height, const int num_structs, __global float3* output)
{
    unsigned int work_item_id = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int x_coord = work_item_id % width;
    unsigned int y_coord = work_item_id / width;

    Test test = tests[0];
    output[work_item_id] = test.b;
}
```

This will do something silly which is just give one of the `float3` arrays as the output, but I just need to know I am actually getting the data through to the kernel properly.

I am trying to mimic an array of these structures on the python side with the following code:

```
class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("a", ctypes.c_float),
        ("b", (ctypes.c_float * 4))
    ]

class Test_Array(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("TEST_ARRAY", ctypes.POINTER(Test))]

    def __init__(self, num_structs):
        elems = (Test * num_structs)()
        self.TEST_ARRAY = ctypes.cast(elems, ctypes.POINTER(Test))
        self.elements = num_structs
        for num in range(0, num_structs):
            self.TEST_ARRAY[num].a = 1.0
            self.TEST_ARRAY[num].b = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

num_structs = 2

test_arr = Test_Array(num_structs)

#host buffer
color_out = np.empty((win.width * win.height, 4), dtype=np.float32)

cl_prog = CL()
cl_prog.load_program("shaders/struct.cl")

#device buffers
cl_structs = cl_prog.create_input_buffer(num_structs * ctypes.sizeof(Test))
cl_output = cl_prog.create_output_buffer(color_out.nbytes)

cl.enqueue_fill_buffer(cl_prog.queue, cl_structs, test_arr.TEST_ARRAY,
 0, num_structs * ctypes.sizeof(Test))

global_work_size = (win.width * win.height,)

cl_prog.program.render_kernel(cl_prog.queue, global_work_size, None,
                              cl_structs, np.int32(win.width), np.int32(win.height), 
                              np.int32(num_structs), cl_output)

cl_prog.retrieve_data(color_out, cl_output)
print(color_out)
```

This isn't really relevant as the functions in this class are just wrappers around pyOpenCL functions, but here is the CL class which is instantiated.

```
class CL:
    def __init__(self):
        self.platform = cl.get_platforms()[0]
        self.device = self.platform.get_devices()[0]
        self.ctx = cl.Context([self.device])
        self.queue = cl.CommandQueue(self.ctx)

    def load_program(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path) as f:
            src = f.read()
            self.program = cl.Program(self.ctx, src).build()

    def create_output_buffer(self, size):
        """
        creates and returns a write only cl.Buffer of size bytes.
        """
        mf = cl.mem_flags
        return cl.Buffer(self.ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, size)

    def create_input_buffer(self, size):
        """
        returns a read only cl.Buffer of size bytes.
        """
        mf = cl.mem_flags
        return cl.Buffer(self.ctx, mf.READ_ONLY, size)

    def retrieve_data(self, host_buffer, device_buffer):
        """
        retrieves data from a buffer on the device, device_buffer, and copies it
        over to host_buffer
        """
        cl.enqueue_copy(self.queue, host_buffer, device_buffer)

    def fill_buffer(self, memory, pattern, offset, size, wait_for=None):
        """
        A wrapper around cl.enqueue_fill_buffer which uses self.queue
        """
        cl.enqueue_fill_buffer(self.queue, memory, pattern, offset, size, wait_for)

    def enqueue_copy(self, device_buffer, host_buffer):
        cl.enqueue_copy(self.queue, device_buffer, host_buffer)
```

When I run the above code, it compiles and runs fine, but the information I get back from the buffer is just garbage that was already in memory. I can't tell if my problem is with alignment of the data, the way I am creating the array of ctypes structs, or what?

I am not attached to using a C array of C structs. I suspect there is a way to do this with numpy arrays, but I can't figure it out. Any way to properly get the data from the host to the device would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggest back in 2014, this could perhaps be done like so:

```
__kernel void render_kernel(struct Params Test, ...){

}
```

You can see this [post.](https://community.khronos.org/t/send-custom-type-to-the-kernel/4682)

Otherwise, something called [Attributes of Variables](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/attributes-variables.html) may be an option?

Hope you got this sorted out and share the experience. I would love to see how this is done as I may want to try pass SQL query over to kernel to process.